# Jquery Mobile Multiline Button

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I set this button multiline?

```
<a style="width:33%; display:inline-block; " href="/foos.html"  data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">a lot of text </a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The above answer given by ppshein is incorrect. It makes a bigger button but doesn't make the button multilined. The only thing you need to do is add the following css:

```
.ui-btn-inner { 
  white-space: normal !important; 
}
```

It works both for button and input tags.

Btw there's a bug for IE: the text in the button isn't clickable. The fix is found at github:

https://github.com/timmywil/jquery-mobile/commit/59a4946d776e9b1f6a75e9eb53ccb38347612125

Comment: I've edited my answer there's a bug for IE you might want to fix

Comment: ok, but the website I'm developping is for Mobile so, I can finally say I don't care IE, however thank you

Answer (score -1):

It's simple. Change existing **.ui-btn-inner** class as follow.

```
.ui-btn-inner { 
    padding: 2em; 
    display: block; 
    height: 100%; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    position: relative; 
}
```

after that, change existing two class as follow

```
<!--- add it after .ui-select ---> 
.ui-select .ui-btn-inner {padding: .6em;} 

<!--- add it after .ui-checkbox ---> 
.ui-checkbox .ui-btn-inner {padding: .6em;}
```

You can visit my blog for detail

[How to make square shape button in jQueryMobile](http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2011/5/17/How-to-make-square-shape-button-in-jQueryMobile)

Comment: ok I've a multiline layout(square shape) but my text doesn't take mutiline

Comment: I don't understand why I tell me to put text-overflow: ellipsis; if it  is not logical for multiline context