# jQuery Mobile: multi-line buttons, in a vertical control group

Tags: jquery-mobile

On my jQuery Mobile page, i'm using a horizontal control group for some buttons.
But in some languages the text within these buttons is too long.

Instead of wrapping the text within each button, the buttons themselves wrap onto the next line.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

this is the base code:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="#pageVertical" data-role="button">short button</a>
    <a href="#pageVertical" data-role="button">really really really insanely long button is really really insanely long. No really, who makes buttons this big?</a>
</div>
```

and with this css, we convince it to wrap inside the buttons. Otherwise the text is truncated with an ellipsis

```
.ui-btn-inner{ 
    white-space: normal !important; 
}
```

On the third page of this fiddle the problem is demonstrated
http://jsfiddle.net/koesper/R8Kwe/

Anyone have any ideas how I might tackle this?

Thanks in advance,
Casper

ps. Inspiration for the original fix came from Tosh in [Jquery Mobile Multiline Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453926/jquery-mobile-multiline-button)

Comment: Oh yeah, it might be worth mentioning that adding a simple <br/> inside the button text is completely ignored.
JQM creates a duplicate of the button without html, and that one is displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set widths for the links in your control-group:

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-controlgroup a {
    width : 49%;
}​
```

This will keep them on the same line. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R8Kwe/6/

Also, just to be thorough, the `white-space : normal` actually needs to be applied to the `.ui-btn-text` element which is a child of the `.ui-btn-inner` element (so it still receives the inherited value).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this could work with some further tweaking (specifying the height as well, so they appear similar).   I was hoping for a solution though that would be a bit more flexible, that would automatically increase the height of all the buttons when one of them needed it.   
I'll wait for another 24 hours to see if someone can help me with that, otherwise I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion on the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koesper/R8Kwe/).  
Hopefully we can further improve this to make better use of the available width

Comment: Marked as accepted, although I'm not completely satisfied yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Trim your long buttons - that's a usability issue. If you have action buttons named that long seems like that just defeats the purpose of an action? Other than that I wouldn't use controlgroups for something like this. I would use a custom data theme & some grids to house my buttons inline.

Comment: You are absolutely right, buttons like this are way too long, that's why I exaggerated the example. In my actual page the text was only a few characters too long to fit on one line. (two long french words, or two short words in english...)